# Change format of a row of cells based on comparing each cell in 2 rows

Tags: excel, vba

In excel 2016 I am using a query to gather data.  In this data both the current inventory and the amount needed for the next 2 days of production.  I want to highlight when the inventory is less than the amount needed.  When I use conditional formatting it looks good initially but then when I update with more data the range of the Conditional format is compromised.  What would be a good way to do this using VBA?

[sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HPb1C.png)

[here is conditional format formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sv1Et.png)

[Conditional Format changing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TDECn.png)

Comment: Why is the conditional formatting compromised? If it is set to these two rows and you have not used locked cell references, the formatting should expand as needed without compromise. I don't think you need VBA for this - can you share your current conditional formatting rule?

Comment: The "Applies to" that is getting compromised.  When I put in the dynamic range it converts to the actual address.  Then when I add more records and update the query the applies to does not update properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without more details it's hard to know what "compromised" is. I'm guessing that the range of the conditional formatting is either not including the new records or being changed by the additional records. Would modifying the range for the conditional formatting to include the whole rows fix the issue? e.g. change `$A$1:$B$5` to `$A:$B`

EDIT:
OK. Try a VBA that clears and resets the conditional formatting every time.

```
Sub Format()
  With ActiveSheet.Rows("$2:$2") ''Select rows your working with
    .FormatConditions.Delete  '' Clear out exising Conditional Formatting in selection
    .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=(A$1>A$2)"  ''Formula where condition is true
    .FormatConditions(.FormatConditions.Count).Interior.Color = 65535 ''Set formatting you color yellow
  End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Greg,  I added another picture that shows the screen shots of the conditional formatting rules manager.  When I start I apply the format to the entire row.  Then when the data set changes from a smaller set(less rows and columns) to a larger set the applies to changes

Comment: Amended my answer. Hopefully this is a solution that will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Greg_D I just found a solution and seen you just posted a solution.  I tried yours and it worked.  I went down another path.

```
Sub Inventory_format()Dim cell As Range
```

For Each cell In Range("SeqInv")

'compair inventory to qtyneeded
'inventory *90% is less than what is required than warning by highlighting in red
'using the named range low_limit so can be changed in the gen setpoints worksheet

If cell.Value * (1 - Range("Low_limit")) < cell.Offset(-1, 0) Then

cell.Interior.Color = VBA.ColorConstants.vbRed

'inventory *70% is less than what is required than warning by yellow

ElseIf cell.Value * (1 - Range("High_limit")) < cell.Offset(-1, 0) Then
cell.Interior.Color = VBA.ColorConstants.vbYellow
Else
cell.Interior.Color = VBA.ColorConstants.vbWhite
End If
Next cell

End Sub